# Django TypeError: 'int' object is not callable when trying save data in models

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am trying to save no of values that a question takes into my model the function to do so is listed below, and the no_value field in Models is IntegerField with default value of 0.

```
def _no_value():
    questions = Question.objects.all()
    for question in questions:
        regex = re.compile('(__[_]*)')
        no_value = (regex.findall(question.question))
        if no_value:
            value = len(no_value)
            question.no_value(value)
            question.save()
```

Please tell me how to fix this error.

Comment: question.no_value = value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**question.no_value is an object from your DB query(questions = Question.objects.all()**
)
If you want to update the value of no_value use the below snippet.

```
question.no_value = value
question.save()
```

or if it is an update

```
question.no_value = question.no_value + value
question.save()
```